# Angular: How to prevent controller reload on state change

Tags: angularjs

I have Settings view and Settings subview:

```
     $stateProvider
        .state('sidemenu.settings', {
                url: '/settings',
                views: {
                    'mainContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/settings/settings.html',
                        controller: 'SettingsController'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('sidemenu.default-location',{
                url: '/default-location',
                views:{
                    'mainContent':{
                        templateUrl: 'partials/settings/defaultLocation.html',
                        controller:'SettingsController'
                    }
                }
            })
```

You can notice that both use the same controller: `SettingsController`.

When I call from main Settings view `$state.go('sidemenu.default-location');` it reloads `SettingsController` again. Why?

*(I don't want to use `ng-show/hide`)*

My question is if I stay in some controller and next state uses the same controller how to prevent controller reload?

Comment: It's not "reloading", it's an entirely new instance of $scope. Try controllerAs. It will still be two separate instances, but you can then identify them individually. Alternatively, you can have multiple controllers on your index page (like a menu controller separate from ui-view). Also, you can use ng-include to pull in a partial. (Just thinking, maybe sidemenu is not actually a separate view).. If it really is separate views, use a service to handle settings, then inject it into your different controllers.

Comment: Controllers are Garbage Collected on route changes. `ui-router-extras` is currently the best solution for fixing your problem: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky